Too basic for quant stackexchange
Forgive me if this is posted elsewhere. I've seen multiple questions put on hold because they are deemed too basic for this site who is intended for professionals. I think, as long as the question is a quantitative finance question and is posed properly, it should be allowed. What is the harm?
example: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20929/basic-fixed-income-securities-two-exercises
Take for example StackOverflow. It is most definitely a source for professionals, but basic questions are asked all the time and answered. Some even have very high upvotes. 

Why the down vote? If you disagree with my suggestion, express your reasoning in a comment/answer. If it is a duplicate, close it.

Note: some of highly-upvoted basic questions on SO are actually off-topic by current rule. Most of them are from 3 years ago or later, back when SO rule was not that strict. However, the community deemed those as useful and decided not to delete, but to lock it instead. But that doesn't mean that kind of question will be accepted if posted now on SO.

To my knowledge, no such rule exists on SO. Can you point me to it? As far as I'm aware,  any programming questions are allowed on SO as long as the OP shows they have tried to solve the problem before turning to so.

On-topicness and Avoid ask on SO help. Also, sample case (posted 7 years ago)

The harm is that the basic questions drive away the real professionals necessary to make this a really interesting website. This has been discussed before and I don't have much to add to that discussion. @TalFishman makes a good point though and I believe in some cases a more basic question is acceptable if it's hard to find a good resource on Google (this will be rare!).

This is a discussion we've been having forever and it was decided that the site should maintain high standards in terms of questions, as you can see on the help-center.
The idea was to attract really people from Quant Finance and avoid having too many CFA-like questions, although we've already answered many of these.
